# Изменение данных графика matplotlib во время работы программы

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Реализую визуализацию классификатора knn. Данные генерирую сам. Сейчас сделал схранение данных в .csv файл. Хочу реализовать кнопку "обновить", которая удалит файл с данными и перезапустит генерацию данных и отрисовку графика. Возможно ли это? 
То есть вопрос в том, возможно ли во время работы программы удалить файлы и отрисовать новый график в том же окне.

*Также мне неизвестно число итераций. Предполагается, что пользователь открывает программу, смотрит на нее, если хочет -- нажимает книпоку "обновить" и так до тех пор, пока он не закроет программу*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос:

```
То есть вопрос в том, возможно ли во время работы программы удалить файлы и отрисовать новый график в том же окне.
```

Ответ: да возможно. А почему вы решили, что нет?

Вот пример последовательной (в цикле) отрисовки разных графиков в одном и том-же окне. На основании этого можно написать то, что вы там себе придумали.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig = plt.figure()  
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
for i in range(5):
    plt.plot(x, i*np.sin(x))
```

Добавление -  ответ на вопрос в комментарии. Бесконечный цикл.

```
i=1
while i>0 :
    plt.plot(x, i*np.sin(x))
    plt.pause(2)
    i=int(input('Введите положительное число. Для окончания работы - отрицательное.'))
```

Comment: А в бесконечный цикл это получится обернуть?

Comment: @DKay Главное, суметь этот бесконечный цикл как-то прервать :-). А так, конечно, возможно. Дополнил ответ выше.

Comment: А ещё вопрос насчёт plt.show(): разве с этим не возникнет проблем? Если ставить после цикла, то сначала программа будет ждать, пока мы введем отрицательное число и только потом построит график, а если до цикла – программа построит пустой график, а после закрытия окна будет ожидать от нас ввод чисел

Comment: Почитайте про использование plt.show() в интерактивных и не интерактивных приложениях :https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.show.html